# Throw Exception inside a Task - "await" vs Wait()

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library, async-await, parallel-extensions

```
static async void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t = new Task(() => { throw new Exception(); });

    try
    {                
        t.Start();
        t.Wait();                
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        // When waiting on the task, an AggregateException is thrown.
    }

    try
    {                
        t.Start();
        await t;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // When awating on the task, the exception itself is thrown.  
        // in this case a regular Exception.
    }           
}
```

In TPL, When throwing an exception inside a Task, it's wrapped with an AggregateException.
But the same is not happening when using the **await** keyword.
What is the explanation for that behavior ?

Comment: ..That's one of benefits of `await`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The goal is to make it look/act like the synchronous version. Jon Skeet does a great job explaining this in his Eduasync series, specifically this post:

http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/06/22/eduasync-part-11-more-sophisticated-but-lossy-exception-handling/

Comment: @Eldho - fixed, although it's odd since I thought the links were going to be fixed automatically.  Oh, well.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237110/is-there-any-support-for-mass-link-editing

Comment: This could greatly use a snippet to the main point that answers OP's question in a nutshell (where the link would expand upon it).

Answer (score 5):

In TPL `AggregateException` is used because you can have multiple tasks in wait operation (task can have child tasks attached), so many of them can throw exceptions. Look at **Exceptions in child tasks** section here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd997417(v=vs.110).aspx

In `await` you always have just one task.

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Links in English are : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good explanation in details, by Stephen Toub, why there is a difference in exception type between Task.Wait() and await:

[Task Exception Handling in .NET 4.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/)

> When designing Task.Wait in .NET 4, we chose always propagating an
>   aggregate.  That decision was influenced by the need to not overwrite
>   details, but also by the primary use case for tasks at the time, that
>   of fork/join parallelism, where the potential for multiple exceptions
>   is quite common.
>
> While similar to Task.Wait at a high level (i.e. forward progress
>   isn’t made until the task completes), “await task” represents a very
>   different primary set of scenarios.  Rather than being used for
>   fork/join parallelism, the most common usage of “await task” is in
>   taking a sequential, synchronous piece of code and turning it into a
>   sequential, asynchronous piece of code.  In places in your code where
>   you perform a synchronous operation, you replace it with an
>   asynchronous operation represented by a task and “await” it.  As such,
>   while you can certainly use await for fork/join operations (e.g.
>   utilizing Task.WhenAll), it’s not the 80% case.  Further, .NET 4.5
>   sees the introduction of
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo, which solves
>   the problem of allowing you to marshal exceptions across threads
>   without losing exception details like stack trace and Watson buckets.
>   Given an exception object, you pass it to
>   ExceptionDispatchInfo.Create, which returns an ExceptionDispatchInfo
>   object that contains a reference to the Exception object and a copy of
>   the its details.  When it’s time to throw the exception, the
>   ExceptionDispatchInfo’s Throw method is used to restore the contents
>   of the exception and throw it without losing the original information
>   (the current call stack information is appended to what’s already
>   stored in the Exception).
>
> Given that, and again having the choice of always throwing the first
>   or always throwing an aggregate, for “await” we opt to always throw
>   the first.  This doesn’t mean, though, that you don’t have access to
>   the same details.  In all cases, the Task’s Exception property still
>   returns an AggregateException that contains all of the exceptions, so
>   you can catch whichever is thrown and go back to consult
>   Task.Exception when needed.  Yes, this leads to a discrepancy between
>   exception behavior when switching between “task.Wait()” and “await
>   task”, but we’ve viewed that as the significant lesser of two evils.